# Mean application on azure webapp

Tags: node.js, azure

i've an application Mean that will deployed on Azure in a continuous delivery.
We have define on VSTS a build script that build typescript to JS file, clean up unuseful files, a gulp task that zip files and finally copy zip files on drop folder.

After on release level we will have a script for IT environment, staging environment.

We have an Azure Web App Deployment task, it takes the zip files and decompress the files rightly.

But if i let the node-modules folder it takes more that 2 hours ...

i search a solution to launch an 'npm instal' after this task.

I know that's possible to go to Kudu and launch the npm install.

I've tested solution with a deploy.sh (see on the net) but task not launch automatically like i see.

I've try to launch a power shell script but it's failed ...

I've the feeling that's not possible except manual intervention via kudu or other .

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, in the Azure Portal go to your Web App then select "Deployment Options".  In there you will see ways to load your app automatically from github, Visual Studio Team Services, OneDrive, and more.

It's all automatic, from the copying of the code to the npm install.  Works great for us for development, test, and production environments using VSTS and we have a node/express/angular app.

Here are the docs for setting up automatic deployment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy

Comment: Where are you deploying from?  Your question makes it seem like you are manually copying files up there and not using deployment from source control.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. We have do it nd we have selected VSTS for source code. Now we have continous delivery activated, In deployment options we have message like we are in continious delivery. I search just to launch the npm install avec unzip on the webapp.... Thanks in advance

Comment: We deploy from VSTS : a build step and a release step. In the release step we have a azure webdeploy. This step take zip on drop folder and unzip on the webapp. Actually we are mandatory to put in the zip the node_modules folder. But it takes many times. What we search is to avoid that. and when the unzip is done launch a npm install in the wwwroot. Is it possible ?

Comment: It happens automatically on our app, there was no configuration required.  Are you running node with app.js or server.js?  Ours uses server.js which I read a long time ago Azure likes better.

Comment: Those are all details you should be adding to your question by the way :)

Comment: Sorry if my response is not clear ... Our process is : we have a project project nodejs, source code is in VSTS. On webapp level we have linked the webapp with the VSTS project like explain below. On webapp level nothing more. On VSTS we have define a build process that take the code source, execute the typescript convert to js, delete some unuseful file, zip the content and copy the zip on the vsts drop folder. In the release step the zip is unzip on the webapp. We want during deploy process launch an npm install. We have try with deploy.cmd. But command file is never launched ... right??

Comment: We manually build our angular app and copy it into the dist folder in node.  When we merge the code into the master branch it automatically uploads everything to Azure then runs npm install.  No custom scripts needed on our end.

Comment: oki for that process. but in company developpers is doing push on development branchand when is planned a configuration manager launch the deploy for test environment. When validate deployment is done in staging ... until prod. So deployment has not to be done on automatic push. Or maybe we have to use a dv branch and apply deploy when merge on master ??? Sorry if mistake in our process is new for us :)

Comment: Yes, you can set up development on a different branch.